# AngularJS and Google Maps - Links on Markers don't recognized on iOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, google-maps

I have an app which loads a map of Google Maps with a set of markers. I have set in each bubble of the markers the html with a link pointing a route (relative url) like this: `#/page/:id`. In android, on touch, the links works perfect. But in iOS the links don't work and I cannot enter the url of the link. It does nothing, throws no error (I am inspecting with Safari web inspector) and don't navigate.

HTML Code of the markers:

```
var content = "<div class='globo_mapa'>
    <div style='max-width: 33%'>
        <img src='"+servicio.service_data[0].picture+"' />
    </div>
    <div style='max-width: 66%'>
        <h3>"+servicio.service_data[0].nombre+"</h3> " + servicio.service_data[0].descripcion+"
    </div>
    <a href='#/dashboard/unique/"+servicio.id_servicio+"'>Ver Servicio</a>  
</div>";
```

Route:

```
.state('dashboard.unique', {
        url:'/unique/:id',
        cache: false,
        resolve: {
          auth: function resolveAuthentication(AuthResolver) {
            return AuthResolver.resolve();
          }
        },
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'closerViews/dashboard/uniqueservice.html',
            controller: 'uniqueController'
          }
        }
    })
```

Is this an iOS feature? Do I have to do something special for this to work in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. There is a bug with iOS 9.x solved in angular and ionic last version. If you are having this issues, like an infinite digest, it is solved updating your angular libraries.